# Gradle MavenDeployer GitLab

Tags: gradle, gitlab

I'd like to set up a git repository on my own gitlab server to store the artifacts for private libraries.

I am not able to find a way to set gitlab + gradle to upload the archives on my git repository.

Is there someone who can post some kind of configuration or step by step guide?

Comment: I don't see how you could. The one trick to abuse Git as a Maven repository is to declare a Maven repo with a local file URL, publish to that, then commit and push the resulting files.

Comment: hmm do you know if there's something that automates this?

Comment: You could leverage one of the third-party Gradle Git plugins to automate this.

Comment: Hello @PeterNiederwieser do you have someone you would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way to do this is to "upload" the archives in a local maven repo and then perform a git commit + git push.

While i'm not an expert on groovy to post your artifacts on your local repo all you need to do is add the following snippet in your *build.gradle* file:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = "your.group"
version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
archivesBaseName = "artifactname"
artifacts {}
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/localRepo').absolutePath
    }
}
task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)enter code here
```